# Is there any other way to find xpath in appium just like we do via firebug?

Tags: android, selenium, appium, android-uiautomator

I am new to Appium and trying to find the xpath to click on elements for an android application, so searched and found we can do that by uiautomator but that's not looks easy, as the tree seems complex and need to create xpath from scratch and sometimes not able to figure out.

So, just a question is there any other tool like firebug by which we can find the absolute xpath directly and later we can convert to relative path if required.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming:* you have a native android application and you are using page object model

You can make use of the name attribute of the elements:

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//*[@name=\"Back\"]")
```

Also, Android Application Development inherently requires(more often than not) developers to assign resource-ids to elements.

So, I suggest you to use:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id=appPackage+":id/action_bar_back")
```

appPackage here being your apps package.

Also, UiAutomator is your go-to tool for android automation. You can use Appium inspector as well.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I am trying to automate the pre installed app in my android phone and I am able to open the same via appium and script but the lens icon is not appearing to open apium inspector in appium window from where I can get the xpath or path. please suggest

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool but you can use UIAUtomatorViewer for getting the attribute values like class,id,name etc and you can write your own xpath.